Prove there exists a prime ideal whose elements are all zero divisors
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $S$ be the set of all elements of $R$ that are not zero divisors. Show that there is a prime ideal $P$ such that $P \cap S$ is empty. The hint that is given suggests that I use Zorn's Lemma to do this.
In the context of using the hint, I'm suspecting that we can construct an increasing (or decreasing?) chain of prime ideals and conclude that there is necessarily a maximal (minimal?) prime ideal. The question is how to do this.
The following is a loose collection of observations that seem pertinent:

(Split $R$ into $S$ and $R \setminus S$) If $S$ is the set of all elements of $R$ that are not zero divisors then $R \setminus S$ is the set of zero divisors in $R$.

If $ab \in R$, then $a$ is in $S$ or $R \setminus S$ and the same follows for $b$.

If $ab=0$ then either $a \in S$ or $b \in S$. This observation looks strikingly similar to the definition of prime ideal.


I understand that the second bullet point sounds trivial to point out, but it seems like it might be a necessary tool for the proof.
